# Moving from one sheet to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, links

I am using a Google Sheets to organize an upcoming project. On the first tab I have every task listed, and who the actor should be for that task. I plan on sharing this sheet with my team.

Is it possible to 'link' one cell in one sheet to a cell in another tab (so they see their name - click on it - and are moved to a specific cell in another tab)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Hyperlink' formula to enable switching between one sheet to another sheet or another spreadsheet when you click on a cell. You need to copy the sheet or spreadsheet URL from the address bar and use it in the 'Hyperlink' URL and also, name the cell text in this formula itself.

Note: For some reasons, if the URL changed then this may not work.

Please refer the screenshot: Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This is great - but it only moves me from one sheet to another - It doesnt move the cursor to the individual cell correct? I used =hyperlink("googlesheetaddress", 'Sheetname'!C7) - this gets me to the sheet - and then names the link what is in the field 'Sheetname'!C7 - but I want to move to that cell directly. Any ideas?